# How to read local kml file and use it in KmlLayer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, kml

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename.kml);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];
while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
   buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
buffer.flush();
KmlLayer kmlLayer = newKmlLayer(mMap,newByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()),getApplicationContext());
kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
```

If i code like this, It's not working correctly.. It return the Error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
W/System.err: at com.google.maps.android.kml.KmlFeatureParser.convertToLatLng(KmlFeatureParser.java:294)
```

Help me to correct this problem

Comment: How many bytes is the file? And how many land in your buffer? Figures please.

Comment: Thank You so much for Ur reply... :-) .     I think, problem is not there.. In android google's **KmlLayer** reads <coordinates> only. But google kml file format is **OGC** [link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference). I don't no to open that ogc kml file in android. Plz help me to solve this issue

Comment: @YogeshB Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SherifElNady Not yet

Comment: Did you find the solution to the problem?